# Can use all oops feature in NodeJs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I am very familiar with some server language like PHP,JAVA,etc. Now i moved on NodeJs. Here is my some question that can we use OOPS feature in NodeJs. that is:-

- Encapsultation
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism

Comment: Simple answer is Yes. However, for these, you can you will have to write your own code to make their behavior match with the other OO languages.

Comment: thanks for reply @AdityaParab, can you please elaborate more.

Comment: I just posted an answer, please read it. :)

Comment: Note that those questions are no more related to NodeJS than they are to JavaScript in any other context. You can also more easily achieve certain programming styles with JavaScript using something like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Comment: Thanks @Marty..,TypeScript is solutions which i looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

For `Encapsultation`, read more about Closures

For `Inheritance` read more about `prototype

For `Polymorphism` there is no direct contruct for polymorphism.

You can implement function overloading by not specifying any parameters to the function and inside your function, you can use `argumets` variable to see number of parameters passed to the function then use constructs like `if/else` or `switch` to change the behavior of your function.

Function overriding can be easily achieved with prototypal inheritance.

I don't know if operator over loading is really possible.

Comment: you clear my concept by giving this helpful answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation is not exclusive to OOP in any way, and is probably possible in every single language. It's more of a design choice, I'd say.

JavaScript features prototypal inheritance. It's a bit different from class inheritance, but it can be used exactly the same way. One could say it's actually more flexible.

Polymorphism... Well, since there is inheritance, there sort of is polymorphism. You can create "classes", inherit from them and override their behaviour. But since the language is dynamically typed, it's hard to talk about the polymorphism you know from, say, Java. A concept you might want to read about is duck typing.

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning duck typing. Most people don't really know about this concept.